# Удаление лишних символов в формуле Notion

Tags: формулы

Я написал формулу в Notion для расчета прибыли. Эта формула выдает расчеты в процентах типа -20.3810453122%

```
((prop("Price, $") - prop("Buy Price, $")) * prop("Total Coins") + prop("Dividends")) / (prop("Buy Price, $") * prop("Total Coins"))
```

Но никак не могу сообразить что дописать, чтобы получить значение вида -20.38%

А так же в этой же формуле не получается добавить символ  перед числом если итоговое значение больше 0 и  если значение меньше 0.

Возможно ли средствами Notion получить такой вид значение  -20.38%, либо  15.15%

Answer (score 0):

Да, возможно. Только для этого не предусмотрено удобных средств форматирования, какие мы привыкли видеть в "продвинутых" языках программирования. Форматирование надо делать своими руками. Чтобы получить два знака после запятой для свойства "Числа", делаем следующее:

```
round( prop("Числа") * 100 ) / 100
```

Ну а в Вашем случае вместо `prop("Числа")` надо написать приведенный Вами код.

Теперь вторая часть вопроса - о символе перед числом. Вполне подойдет следующая формула:

```
concat(if(prop("Числа") > 0, "", ""), format(round(prop("Числа") * 100) / 100))
```

Возможно, она покажется длинной и трудночитаемой, если производить подстановку в нее Вашего кода. Но тут есть обходной путь: создайте дополнительное свойство, аналогичное моему "Числа", запишите туда свою формулу для вычисления прибыли, а уже в следующем свойстве займитесь его форматированием, используя написанный выше код.